# Pass long and lat to calculate short distanace with Pythagoras

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to calculate short distances(4-5 meter) between two points with the Pythagoras formula but I am getting result like `1.1979775925924383E7, 1.1979777593853703E7, 1.1979940093453636E7`  for distance between two points. what does that mean?

I passed to the function the latitude and longitude like this 80.234578 also with 6 digits after the comma.

```
    private double pyth(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2,
        double lon2) {

    final int R = 6371 * 1000; // Radious of the earth in meter
     double x = toRad(lon2-lon1);
     double y = toRad(lat1+lat2);

     double distance = Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y)*R;
     return distance;
}

private double toRad(double value) {
    return value * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

Comment: In what way is this Java? Please don't just provide pseudo-code - provide real code, with actual inputs and expected outputs. It's not clear how you reached the code you've got, either. I suggest you look at the Haversine formula... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Comment: @Jon I have tested the harersine formula and many people said it is overkill for short distance.

Comment: @Dmitry: And how should I put them? sorry I didnot understand your point.

Comment: It may be overkill, but it feels like it's the right domain - currently you're treating radians as distances, which sounds like a bad idea to me. You've apparently changed the tag to `javascript` but now the code looks more like Java, which is an entirely different language. You still haven't provided a short but complete program with real inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs...

Comment: @Jon: I have already implemented  the code from the client as well as from the server side but  it is too much lines I cant past everything here. I have tested haversine formula before I got distance with acceptable result but as I said someone told me to use Pythagoras approach for that it is more appropriate. And I have tested this `pythagoras` function above in the question but as I said I got these values `1.1979775925924383E7, 1.1979777593853703E7, 1.1979940093453636E7 ` I dont know what does that mean.

Comment: What client? what server? You're being *very* vague here, and we *still* don't know what language you actually care about. Likewise you've provided us with three outputs, but without the inputs they're meaningless. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints for guidance as to what makes a *good* Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the algorithm described here:

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Esp. section "Equirectangular approximation", looks like parts of those formulas were blended into a new form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the difference of the latitudes, not the sum.  That will give you answers that are only slightly wrong because it pretends the earth is flat (the longitude should be multiplied by the cosine of the latitude).  I've also changed `x` and `y` to `dx` and `dy`, since that's more descriptive.

```java
private double pyth(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    final int R = 6371 * 1000; // Radius of the earth in meter
    double dx = toRad(lon2-lon1)*Math.cos((lat1+lat2)/2);
    double dy = toRad(lat1-lat2);

    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)*R;
}

private double toRad(double value) {
    return value * Math.PI / 180;
}
```